# Locally flat manifold from Frobenius, differential forms approach

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, differential-forms

It is a known fact that a Manifold $M$ is locally flat if and only if the Riemann curvature tensor (Levi-Civita connection) vanishes. To show the if part is easy, but I am trying to follow the details of the proof given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrability_conditions_for_differential_systems) but I am at a loss in reaching a full proof. I am interested only in a proof of this statement using the Frobenius theorem.

**Here is what I have tried**: We start with a coframe $\Phi$, it obeys the structure equations ($R=0,~T=0$)

$$
d\Phi + \omega \wedge \Phi =0, \qquad d\omega + \omega \wedge \omega=0
$$
from the second equation it can be seen (Frobenius thm) that the first equation is integrable. Now, since $\Phi$ is a coframe I can ask whether a local rotation matrix $R(x) \in SO(n)$ will be capable of rotating the coframe $\Phi$ to a closed coframe $\Theta$, $d\Theta=0$ (If we manage to do that then Poincaré lemma implies that $\Theta = d \Psi$ locally, and such $\Psi$ are the sought euclidean coordinate functions, we are done). Calculation gives:

$$
d(R \Phi) = d \Theta = (dR - R \omega)\wedge \Phi
$$
and this will vanish if the equation $R^{-1}dR = \omega $ is solved by some $R$. I can see that the structural equation implies the integrability of this equation, so a solution $R$ exists, but how can we be sure that such solution will be a matrix in $SO(n)$?

**Here is my question:** How do we know that there is an $R \in SO(n)$ that solves $dR = R \omega$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Élie Cartan, you want to think of your differential system $dR - R\omega = 0$ on $M\times SO(n)$. This $\mathfrak{so}(n)$-valued $1$-form is integrable, as you said, because of vanishing curvature. The integral manifolds of this differential system will locally be the graphs of functions $R\colon U\to SO(n)$.

Comment: But what if I chose $SO(n-1,1)$ or $O(n)$, $SL(\mathbb{R},n)$, $GL(\mathbb{R},n)$,or $Spin(n)$? Why $SO(n)$ and not any other Lie group $\times M$? What makes $SO(n)$ special? I know it must be a consequence of the fact that $M$ is a Riemannian manifold, but it is not clear to me at all why this is so. Even if we grant that is must be $SO(n)$, then how does integrability on $M \times SO(n)$ follow from the structural equations? I can see only integrability on $M$. Is it possible to integrate the system on $M \times SO(n-2,n)$ for instance, if $n>2$?

Comment: Because you're doing Riemannian curvature, the curvature $2$-form is $\mathfrak{so}(n)$-valued. No, this differential system is on $M\times SO(n)$, not on $M$, since $R$ is $SO(n)$-valued.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but just to be sure that I follow: It is always true then that the connection form $\omega \in \Omega^{1}(M) \otimes \mathfrak{so} (n)$ when $M$ is Riemannian? Is there some elementary way to see this?

Comment: When you have a Riemannian structure, you are working with the (oriented) orthonormal frame bundle, which is why your structure group is $(S)O(n)$. As always, the connection form takes values in the Lie algebra of the structure group. (Think about the Maurer-Cartan matrix $g^{-1}dg$.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience, I now see what is going on, $\omega$ is a connection in the frame bundle! That is why it is valued on $\mathfrak{so}(n)$. It is clear now, I will have to look up those details, but now I know why. Thanks again.